# Vuex not loading

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have installed a brand new version of Vuex into a laravel/vue set up

I import the store into app.js

```
import store from './store';
```

I then use it here

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store,
    components: { App },
    router
});
```

and then in my store/index.js file

```
// import dependency to handle HTTP request to our back end
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import axios from 'axios';

//load Vuex
Vue.config.devtools = true;
Vue.use(Vuex);

//to handle state
const state = {
    videos: [],
    test: ''
}

//to handle state
const getters = {}

//to handle actions
const actions = {
    getVideos({commit}) {
        axios.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .then(response => {
                commit('SET_POSTS', response.data)
            })
    }
}

//to handle mutations
const mutations = {
    SET_POSTS(state, payload) {
        state.videos = payload
    }
}

//export store module
export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

I think run npm run watch and build it all out, I get the following error

'No Veux store detected'

Also

```js
this.$store.dispatch('getVideos');
```

errors with
[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.$store.dispatch is not a function"

Comment: odd error seems there's a typo in it

Comment: in vue dev tools sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it like that.

in store/account.js

```
import landlordService from '../service/landlord'
const landlord = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('landlord'));
const state = landlord
    ? {
        status: {
            loggedIn: true
        },
    }
    : {
        status: {},

    };


const actions = {
    login({commit}, { email, password }) {
        commit('loginRequest', { email });
        landlordService.auth( email, password)
            .then(landlord => {
                commit('loginSuccess', landlord);
            }).catch(() => {
                commit('loginFailure')
            })
    },
    logout({ commit }) {
        localStorage.removeItem('landlord')
        commit('logout');
    },
};
const mutations = {
    loginRequest(state, landlord) {
        state.status = { loggingIn: true };
        state.landlord = landlord;
    },
    loginSuccess(state, data) {
        state.status = { loggedIn: true };
        state.landlord = {
            id: data.id,
        };
    },
    loginFailure(state) {
        state.status = {};
        state.landlord = null;
    },
    logout(state) {
        state.status = {};
        state.landlord = null;
    },
};
export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    actions,
    mutations
};
```

Especially you miss here
in store/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import account  from './account';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        account
    }
});
```